# FFmpeg getting issue while creating input with png ,video,draw text

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am getting an error "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_drawtext_3" for the below command, I don't know where it is going wrong. Can anyone help with this issue?

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -i test.mp4 -y -filter_complex [1:v]scale=1152:648[scale0];[scale0]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=304.2:172.29;drawtext=fontfile=test.ttf:text=hi text:fontsize=40:fontcolor=white:x=426.05:y=852.04 -pix_fmt yuv420p est.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.png -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1152:648,rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=304.2:172.29,drawtext=fontfile=test.ttf:text='hi text':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white:x=426.05:y=852.04,format=yuv420p" est.mp4
```

- Join [simple filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs) with a comma. This makes a filterchain.
- Join filterchains or [complex filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Complex-filtergraphs) with a semicolon (`;`).
- Wrap the filtergraph (the complete line of filters) in double quotes (`"`) and the drawtext `text` in single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Thank you, But I am using fluent FFmpeg node library, Is there any fix for that

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Sorry, but I don't know anything about that.